# How to use call backs in C++ like delegates in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, callback, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a C++ delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568150/what-is-a-c-delegate)

I need to use a [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) in C++ like delegates in C#. For example, in C# we have:

```
...
      public delegate void SomeWorkhandeler(object Arg);
...
class A
{
    private SomeWorkhandeler doWork= null;
    public SomeWorkhandeler DoWork { get { return doWork; } set { doWork= value; } }
}
```

Now, what is the C++ code similar to this example?

Comment: See this link: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: but it doesn't declare how work with setter and getter!