# C++ Call Pointer To Member Function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a list of pointers to member functions but I am having a difficult time trying to call those functions... whats the proper syntax?

```
typedef void (Box::*HitTest) (int x, int y, int w, int h);

for (std::list<HitTest>::const_iterator i = hitTestList.begin(); i != hitTestList.end(); ++i)
{
    HitTest h = *i;
    (*h)(xPos, yPos, width, height);
}
```

Also im trying to add member functions to it here

```
std::list<HitTest> list;

for (std::list<Box*>::const_iterator i = boxList.begin(); i != boxList.end(); ++i)
{
    Box * box = *i;
    list.push_back(&box->HitTest);
}
```

Comment: define "having a difficult time"

Comment: Its not working lol and I can't get it to work

Comment: Are you sure you want to do things this way, and not using a list of Box elements and a virtual function?

Comment: The first code I am getting the error

"error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression"

For the second code snippit I am getting the syntax error

"Error: Expression must have a pointer type" with that syntax"

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Pointers to *non-static member functions* are a unique beast with unique calling syntax.

Calling those functions require you to supply not just named parameters, but also a `this` pointer, so you must have the `Box` pointer handy that will be used as `this`.

```
(box->*h)(xPos, yPos, width, height);
```

Comment: I get the error "Error: Expression must have a pointer type" with that syntax.

Comment: @JC. Here, try this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/macro-for-ptr-to-memfn.html

Comment: Something like `((*this).*h)(xPos, yPos, width, height)` but I prefer to stay away

Comment: The issue there is that I am traversing the list of member function pointers and calling each function in another object not of the type that owns the method. Where I am calling the member function pointer I do not have the instance of the object that has the member function I am calling

Comment: @JC That won't work. You need both: An object that will act as `this`, and a pointer to a non-static member function.

Comment: Ah bummer... I'm essentially trying to simulate "events" by registering a bunch of instance member methods into a list in another class so I can iterate through them and call them, so that those instances are "listening" to this class that is maintaining the list and can react when something happens. Maybe there is a better approach in C++?

Answer (score 15):

Calling a member function through a pointer to member function
has a particular syntax:

```
(obj.*pmf)( params );   //  Through an object or reference.
(ptr->*pmf)( params );  //  Through a pointer.
```

Although `->*` can be overridden, it isn't in the standard
library iterators (probably because it would require overrides
for every possible function type).  So if all you've got is an
iterator, you'll have to dereference it and use the first form:

```
((*iter).*pmf)( params );
```

On the other hand, iterating over a the pointer to members
themselves doesn't have this problem:

```
(objBox.*(*i))( params );   //  If objBox is an object
(ptrBox->*(*i))( params );  //  If ptrBox is a pointer
```

(I don't think you need the parentheses around the `*i`, but the
pointer to member syntax is already special enough.)

Answer (score 10):

From my "award winning" ;-) answer about delegates (available at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568150/what-is-a-c-delegate/9568226#9568226) :

Typedef the pointer to member function like this:

```
typedef void (T::*fn)( int anArg );
```

Declare one like this:

```
fn functionPtr = &MyClass::MyFunction
```

Call it like this:

```
(MyObject.*functionPtr)( argument );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt to get a member function pointer through an object betrays a misunderstanding. Member function pointers do not include a pointer to the object you call them on. You have to provide such a pointer at the point of the call.

As many have pointed out, the syntax for a member function call is either:

```
 obj.*funcptr(args);
```

or

```
 objptr->*funcptr(args);
```

In the example you've given, it sounds like what you really need is a virtual function. You have a standard operation (detecting wether or not an object intersects with a box) that needs to be called on many different types of objects, the type of which can't be known at compile time. This is a job that is cut out for virtual functions.