# Calling Member function pointers from vector list

Tags: c++

I'm new to function pointers and I wrote a small program, where main class use Test class to populate a list with member function pointers.  And from my main class I want to call ExeFuns() to call each member function, which I'm not sure how to do. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Test.h**

```
Class Test{
  public : 
   void CallFun1(); 
   void CallFun2();

   void AddFuns(); 
   void ExeFuns();      
};
```

**Test.cpp**

```
std::vector<void (Test::*) ()> callist; 


void Test::AddFuns(){
  callist.push_back(&Test::CallFun1); 
  callist.push_back(&Test::CallFun2); 
}


void Test::ExeFuns(){
  for (int i = 0 ; i<eventlist.size(); i++)
  {
   callist[i](); // error!
  }
}

void Test::CallFun1(){ cout<<"Fun 1"<<endl; }
void Test::CallFun2(){ cout<<"Fun 2"<<endl; }
```

**Main.cpp**

```
main()
{
Test obj; 
obj.AddFuns(); 
obj.ExeFuns(); 
}
```

Comment: You need an object to call them on.

Comment: If you have a C++11 compatible compiler (almost all are today), then you might want to look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). If you don't have C++11, then [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/function.html) and [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bind/bind.html) do the same.

Comment: Oh, and you have a off-by-one error in your `ExeFuns` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you need .* or -> operators to invoke member methods.
Also, there are several compilation errors and one out of bounds access in your code.
Here is the correct approach,

```
void Test::ExeFuns(){
  for (int i = 0 ; i<callist.size(); i++) // also there is out of bounds access (usage of <=) in your code
  {
    (this->*callist[i])(); // or (*this.*callist[i])();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. How would I get the same result if I use vector::pop_back()?

Comment: pop_back doesn't return any value, hence you can't use it to invoke the method, but you can still use vector::back() as (this->*callist.back())();

Answer (score 0):

Those are not pointers to standalone functions, they are pointers to member functions of a class. As chris said, you need an object to call them on.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814158/c-call-pointer-to-member-function) SO question.