# One class method call another one via function pointer

Tags: c++

For some reason I have to call class method from another method of the same class via function pointer. 
This is and example code which illustrates my question:

```
class testClass 
{
....
private:
void method(int parameter) {
    .....
};
void callingMethod();
};
typedef  void (testClass::*classMethod)(int parameter);

void testClass::callingMethod() {
    classMethod method = &testClass::method;
    method(1);
}
```

I get compilation error

error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments.

What is a right method to do such calls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Call Pointer To Member Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814158/c-call-pointer-to-member-function)

Comment: I guess so, just can't find the write syntax for this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct except that instead of

```
method(1);
```

you should use

```
(this->*method)(1);
```

or

```
(*this.*method)(1);
```

Comment: Thank you. My real case has a table of method pointers, do member method pointer, which get value form the table do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
class testClass 
{
     public:
     int method(int parameter) 
     {
        cout << "Hi";
        return 0;
     };

     void callingMethod();
};


int (testClass::*pt2Member)(int) = NULL;

void testClass::callingMethod()
{
     pt2Member = &testClass::method;
     (*this.*pt2Member)(12);
     //classMethod method = &testClass::method;
     //*method(1);
}

int main()
{
    testClass objTest;
    objTest.callingMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be simply

```
(this->*method)(10);
```

Comment: They want to call it via a member pointer not directly, therefore is this answer wrong