# Unknown Syntax void (Type::m_function)()

Tags: c++

I am currently reading through some code and came across a few lines I do not understand.

First

```
void Foo()
{
    (((Type*)parent)->*m_function)();
}
```

As far as I can tell they are casting the parent to Type and then calling a dereferenced function? I am not sure I have seen the ->*m_function before.

Also I can not see where m_function is declared perhaps here? Which contains more syntax I do not understand. Is it declaring a function that returns void and takes a parameter of a function? But where is the function name?

```
class Foo()
{
    void (Type::*m_function)();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's calling a member function using a pointer to this function: [C++ Call Pointer To Member Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814158/c-call-pointer-to-member-function)

Yes, `void (Type::*m_function)();` declares `m_function` member of type "member function of Type taking 0 args and returning void"