# Calling member function by pointer

Tags: c++11, arduino-esp32

I'm developing on an ESP32 with vscode and the ESPAsyncWebServer and Wifi libraries.
I'm tring to make my own wifi manager, so I'd like to put some function in a class, but I've some trouble to point to member functions.

I have this definitions without class:

```
void onNotFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
  //Handle Unknown Request
  request->send(404);
}

String processor(const String& var)
{
  if(var == "HELLO_FROM_TEMPLATE")
    return F("Hello world!");
  return String;
}
```

I want to call them from a class witch is:

My_Wifi.h

```
class My_Wifi {
    private:
        Config *config;
        DNSServer dnsServer;
        AsyncWebServer server;
        uint16_t serverPort = 80;
        void onNotFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request);   <------
        String processor(const String& var);   <-----
        void webServerSetup();
    public:
        My_Wifi();
        void setup(uint16_t port);
        void sendJsonDoneResponse(AsyncWebServerRequest *request);

};
```

My_Wifi.cpp

```
void My_Wifi::onNotFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {...}

String My_Wifi::processor(const String& var) {...}

void My_Wifi::webServerSetup() {
  
  this->dnsServer.start(53, "*", WiFi.softAPIP());

  this->server.onNotFound(this->onNotFound);  <------

  this->server
    .serveStatic("/wifi_settings.html", SPIFFS, "/wifi_settings.html")
    .setTemplateProcessor(this->processor)    <------
    .setFilter(ON_STA_FILTER);

...
}
```

Obviously this it's only to call the function not to reference it.

How can I call a member function via pointer ?

Thanks for your time.

I tryed:

```
typedef void (My_Wifi::*onNotFoundFn)(AsyncWebServerRequest *request);

void My_Wifi::webServerSetup() {
  
  this->dnsServer.start(53, "*", WiFi.softAPIP());

  onNotFoundFn ptr = &My_Wifi::onNotFound;
  this->server.onNotFound(*ptr); //this->server.onNotFound(ptr);
  ...
}
```

Comment: (`this->*pointerToMemberFunction)(parameters)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Call Pointer To Member Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814158/c-call-pointer-to-member-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call member functions, you'll need to supply the object the member function is supposed to be called upon and it should match

```cpp
typedef std::function<String(const String&)> AwsTemplateProcessor;
```

Example using a lambda, capturing `this`:

```cpp
.setTemplateProcessor([this](const String& str) { return processor(str); } )
```

---

A similar lambda for `onNotFound` which should match

```cpp
typedef std::function<void(AsyncWebServerRequest *request)> ArRequestHandlerFunction;
```

would look like this:

```cpp
server.onNotFound([this](AsyncWebServerRequest* r) { onNotFound(r); });
```

Since you do not actually use `this` in your `onNotFound` callback, you *could* make your current callback function `static`:

```cpp
class My_Wifi {
    private:
        static void onNotFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request);
```

and supply that without a lambda:

```cpp
server.onNotFound(&My_Wifi::onNotFound);
```

Alternatively, do not create a member function at all. Just supply a lambda:

```cpp
server.onNotFound([](AsyncWebServerRequest* request){ request->send(404); });
```

Comment: Ok, good! So if I do server.onNotFound([this](AsyncWebServerRequest* r) { this->onNotFound(r); }); with the THIS it refer to the member ? and same for .setTemplateProcessor([this](const String& str) { return this->processor(str); } ) ?

Comment: @JB_DELR Yes, if you do it in a member function of `My_Wifi` then `this` will point at that instance of `My_Wifi`. You don't even need `this->`

Comment: AS I'm from php, this-> is clear for me and better to read me.
So it's typedef sdt::function<returnType(paramType *param)> functionType !, not sure of the last one.

Comment: @JB_DELR Sure, use `this->` if you want, no harm.  `ArRequestHandlerFunction` is a typedef for the signature the callback for `onNotFound` must have and `ArRequestHandlerFunction` is a typedef for the signature of the `TemplateProcessor` callback (whatever that is - no clue myself) :-)

Comment: Ha! with lambda, I don't need the typedef !!!

Comment: @JB_DELR No, _you_ don't need to add any `typedef`s. The two I mentioned are in the ESPAsyncWebServer library already :-)