# What does this declaration typedef void foo(); mean?

Tags: c, typedef, variable-declaration, function-declaration

I don't understand the meaning of `typedef void interrupt_handler();`. Could someone explain it with some examples?

```
typedef void interrupt_handler();
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It means that `interrupt_handler` is type synonym for function, that returns `void` and does not specify its parameters (so called old-style declaration). See following example, where `foo_ptr` is used as function pointer (this is special case where parentheses are not needed):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void interrupt_handler();

void foo()
{
    printf("foo\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    void (*foo_ptr_ordinary)() = foo;
    interrupt_handler *foo_ptr = foo; // no need for parantheses

    foo_ptr_ordinary();
    foo_ptr();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have this function void cpu_boot(uint cores, interrupt_handler bootfunc, uint serialno) and in argument bootfunc i want to pass the following arguments: Task boot_task, int argl, void* args. Task is type typedef int (* Task)(int, void*); How can i implement it? something like wrapper function? @cmbasnett

Comment: @LefterisSarantaris: I would rather ask it in separate question. Don't forget to describe what you have already tried, explain your issue and add some minimal example of it.

Answer (score 9):

It's a `typedef` declaration of a [function pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) with a particular signature (in this case a function with a `void` return and no arguments).

See [What is a C++ delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568150/what-is-a-c-delegate) (top answer, option 3)